# Dask distributed worker unresponsive

Tags: python-3.x, dask, dask-distributed

I am using Dask to parallelize my conversion process. This is achieved by running the conversion process as a subprocess inside each task. The conversion process that I run consumes maximum of 2GB of memory and takes around 30s to complete. The Dask uses YarnCluster.

When I run my process with small number of files it works fine. But when I scale up the tasks to more than 1000, the workers start to fail with the message:

```
distributed.core - INFO - Event loop was unresponsive in Worker for 29.41s.  This is often caused by long-running GIL-holding functions or moving large chunks of data. This can cause timeouts and instability.
```

From the error message I could rule out moving of large chunks of data, as I am not sending or receiving huge amounts of data between any workers or scheduler. Which leaves me with the GIL-holding functions. I am not understanding what is holding the GIL in my process.

Below is the configuration I am using:

```
YarnCluster(environment=f'python://{sys.executable}',
            name='Converter', n_workers=200, worker_vcores=1, worker_memory='4GiB')
client = Client(cluster)
```

The function that runs on the worker looks like this:

```
def convert_file(input_file, output_file):
    p = subprocess.Popen(f'python3 converter.py {input_file} {output_file}', shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    if p.returncode !=0:
        return 0
    return 1
```

The tasks are submitted using `client.submit(convert_file, input_file, output_file)` in an iterative way as described [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html#waiting-on-futures).

The `converter.py` reads the data, processes it and writes it to the output file. The processing involves pandas.

### UPDATE

I went through the logs of the dask and found that the workers are exceeding the memory limits. I am also logging the amount of memory consumed by the `converter.py` process. But nowhere the memory is even close to the limit in the conversion process. Does the dask worker actually store some information in the memory every time a task is completed? I also tried to cancel the futures after its completion in the scheduler, but didn't help.

Comment: Does your computation still complete? The "event loop was unresponsive" message is actually not an error, but a warning. Often, tasks complete without problems.

Comment: Well I had checked this message in a worker which got failed. But later I realized that this message appears in every worker. The real reason the worker got failed was because of memory overflow. I have mentioned in the UPDATE. I am not understanding what is consuming memory in the worker.

Comment: did you actually see a process allocating a lot of memory, e.g. by observing top?

Comment: What I do is within the python task running on the worker I check for the memory consumption using `psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss`. I keep checking and logging the memory consumption continuously so I know that it is not crossing the memory limit.

Comment: When you say "I know that it is not crossing the memory limit." ... you mean you have checked the memory consumption and found that it is not crossing the limit?

Comment: Any luck @leshravnya? I have the same issue.

Comment: @FredericoSchardong The problem that i was facing was the memory consumption was not reporting in real time using `psutil`. In actual the memory consumption of the worker was exceeding the limits. I found this out by just running the worker task individually and monitoring the memory consumption using top.